# New question based on an existing question on Minimum and Maximum of N(0,1)

Tags: self-study, expected-value, extreme-value

This question is an additional question to the given posted here: [Variance of Minimum and Maximum of 2 iid Normal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288491/variance-of-minimum-and-maximum-of-2-iid-normal/288492#288492)

Let $X, Y$ be independent $N(0,1)$ and let $M=Max(X,Y)$. In the previous problem, what was being asked was the covariance between $M$ and $m=Min(X,Y)$. My question is what if the only requirement is to find $E(M)$? Is it necessary to define $Min(X,Y)$ and use it to eventually solve for $E(M)$?

Comment: The symmetry of the Normal distribution implies $-m$ and $M$ are identically distributed. Introducing $m$ evidently wouldn't create anything new.

Comment: @whuber But it is still necessary to deduce that $2E(M)=E|X-Y|$?

Comment: Why?  There usually are many ways to derive almost any result.  This one is no exception, as Glen_b's answer shows in the thread you reference.  Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: You're right. I missed that.